# How do I configure texstudio to print pdf

Tags: printing

I updated to TeXstudio 2.12.6 (hg 6632:7777b2b8a906)
Using Qt Version 5.9.1, compiled with Qt 5.9.1 R

Previously, I could print the pdf file that was created when I compiled the tex file by opening the file tab and choosing print. No longer. The only options now are "open", "split and merge" and "quit texstudio."

What are the detailed instructions to configure texstudio so that I can print the pdf?

Comment: which operating system do you have?

Comment: I use Windows 7 PC

Comment: I found the terse answer to a similar question "Although in the windowed mode the pdf viewer can print through lp/ghostscript" but I don't know how to implement this

Comment: History: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1106/ which might be of interest. Basically, I think if your question is about printing PDF via ghostscript then TeX.SE might not be the best place to ask. Aside, what's wrong with opening it up in a PDF viewer and printing from there?

Answer (score 1):

TeXstudio saves a pdf in the working directory when you compile it. Open the pdf in the pdf viewer of your choice and print it from there. Several free pdf viewers are available online.

Answer (score 0):

In linux version of the TexStudio in embedded viewer you can find option `View`->`External viewer`. It opens you pdf file in the previously configured or default pdf viewer, where you can print your document.